# Get the Filesystem Directory Sizes using Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hdfs, bigdata, hiveql

I have loaded my filesystem information to Hive on a daily basis and I want to do get all directory sizes only.

I have a table like this

```
Path                   Size               Date
/                        0             01-07-2021
/tmp                     0             01-07-2021
/tmp/file1               2             01-07-2021
/tmp/file2               2             01-07-2021
/tmp/dir1                0             01-07-2021
/tmp/dir1/file3          3             01-07-2021
/opt/                    0             01-07-2021
/opt/file1               2             01-07-2021
/opt/dir1                0             01-07-2021
/opt/dir1/file2          3             01-07-2021
/opt/dir2/               0             01-07-2021
/opt/dir2/file3          4             01-07-2021
...
...
...
/                        0             02-07-2021
/tmp                     0             02-07-2021
/tmp/file1               2             02-07-2021
/tmp/file2               2             02-07-2021
/tmp/dir1                0             02-07-2021
/tmp/dir1/file3          3             02-07-2021
/opt/                    0             02-07-2021
/opt/file1               2             02-07-2021
/opt/dir1                0             02-07-2021
/opt/dir1/file2          3             02-07-2021
/opt/dir2/               0             02-07-2021
/opt/dir2/file3          4             02-07-2021
```

And I want to have an output query or create a new table like this.

```
Path                   Size               Date
/                        16            01-07-2021
/tmp                     7             01-07-2021
/tmp/dir1                3             01-07-2021
/opt                     9             01-07-2021
/opt/dir1                3             01-07-2021
/opt/dir2                4             01-07-2021
...
...
...
/                        16            02-07-2021
/tmp                     7             02-07-2021
/tmp/dir1                3             02-07-2021
/opt                     9             02-07-2021
/opt/dir1                3             02-07-2021
/opt/dir2                4             02-07-2021
```

I'm new with SQL please help me. Thank you.

Comment: If this is for hive, why did you also use the `mysql` tag?

Comment: MySQL is also ok as long as I can translate the idea to Hive. Any input is good.

Comment: Not everything in mysql translates to hive or vice versa. If the requirement is to run in hive, not in mysql, then please remove the mysql tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no HiveQL expert, but from what I've briefly read, it doesn't support recursive queries very well. So here's a brute force approach.

It splits the file paths up in to parts, then aggregates them back again such that each file is duplicated for every parent directory.  Then aggregates every file that shares a parent directory.

Hopefully some one gives a better answer.

```
select sub_path, sum(size) as size, date
from
(
  select path, size, date, concat_ws('/', collect_list(b.element)) as sub_path
  from YourTable
  lateral view outer posexplode(split(path, '/')) a as pos, element
  lateral view outer posexplode(split(path, '/')) b as pos, element
  where b.pos <= a.pos
  group by path, size, date, a.pos
)
  sub_paths
group by sub_path, date
```

I recommend testing the sub query on its own, for a small test set of dummy data (just a couple of files in a couple of directories).  That will demonstrate what it's doing, and help you debug any typos.

It also assumes that there are no messy directory or file names containing escaped slashes. This code won't recognise that the slash has been escaped, and consider it a normal slash, representing a new level in the directory structure.

Comment: Hive is really weird with respect to `collect_list()` and the ordering of the elements.  I speculate that your code probably works.  However, explicit ordering would ensure that the resulting paths are actually the original paths and not in some arcane order.  However, you might check out my answer which offers a similar but simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

MatBaille is on the right track.  The idea is to multiply each row for each level in the directory and then aggregate.  I think a safer approach is to use `substring_index()`, which behaves as it does in MySQL.  This does require generating a series of numbers, which uses the `split(spaces)` hack:

```
select substring_index(path, pe.i) as path,
       max(case when path = substring_index(path, i) then date end) as date,
       sum(size) as total_size
from (select t.*,
             1 + length(path) - length(replace(path, '/', '')) as depth
      from t
     ) t lateral view
     posexplode(split(space(t.depth))) pe as i, x
group by substring_index(path, pe.i);
```